# Writing to iPhone Console from c code while running Automation instruments

Tags: ios, c

I am trying to debug a location aware application, which makes use of a C library, which is included as source code files and compiled into the application.

To allow me to test location changes, with direction and speed, in various countries I am using Automation in Instruments and calling setLocationWithOptions to perform the location update from a script.

This prevents me from attaching the Xcode debugger, so I cannot place any breakpoints in the C library code. I am trying to log information to the iPhone console, the one that can be accessed through Organizer. I can see all of the NSLog calls in the console, however I cannot find a way to get log entries out of the C code.

I have tried using syslog to get messages to appear

```
const char* myApp = "MYAPP";
openlog(myApp, LOG_NOWAIT, LOG_USER);
syslog(LOG_DEBUG, "%s", "This is my first log message");
```

However this only seems to work sometimes and is very inconsistent.

Is there another way to get log messages out of C code when running an application on a device through Instruments?

Comment: Can you just write an Objective-C function to call `NSLog` for you?